# Is Dina Demalchutah ever mentioned in Tannaic sources?

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, dina-dmalchusa-dina

I was looking up in the Sefaria, but the only reference to the Dinah Demalchutah I could find was in the Babylonian Talmud in the name of the Babylonian Amorah Shmuel ([דינא דמלכותא](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%90&tab=text&tpathFilters=Talmud&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance)) and only in his name. It does not seem to appear in the Jerusalem Talmud.

Is there a Tannaic source for this fundamental Halachic principle?

Comment: The term appears in the Zohar. Does that count?

Comment: @Harel13 many would say the zohar was not written by the tanna despite its claim

Comment: @ezra true, but that doesn't necessarily dispute its status as a tannaitic text, given that most if not all of the sages mentioned there are Tannaim.

Comment: The phrase is Aramaic while most Tannaitic material is Hebrew.

Comment: רַבִּי חֲנִינָא סְגַן הַכֹּהֲנִים אוֹמֵר, הֱוֵי מִתְפַּלֵּל בִּשְׁלוֹמָהּ שֶׁל מַלְכוּת, שֶׁאִלְמָלֵא מוֹרָאָהּ, אִישׁ אֶת רֵעֵהוּ חַיִּים בְּלָעוֹ. ([Avot 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.3.2))

Comment: @DoubleAA Exactly, and it doesn’t appear in Yerushalmi. Was it a Babylonian invention?

Comment: @AlBerko without a doubt the term is indeed Babylonian Aramaic. But who cares?

Comment: @DoubleAA I do. I'm trying to trace the development of fundamental Halachic concepts. Many of them just pop up at some (relatively late) point in time. If so I'm trying to make sense of the Chiddush - for example, why didn't the Israeli Rabbi think to accept gentile (Roman) rules while Babylonian did? Why Shmuel, he studied in Israel also. Etc.

Comment: You just made up a lot of things. You care which terms are in what languages? The term "milchig" is yiddish. So what?

Comment: I'm sure there's some academic out there who has theorized that the Israeli sages were mostly against non-Jewish rule, which ties into the various rebellions that were there, whilst the Babylonians were okay with it (during most of the Tannaitic era they were ruled by the friendly Parthians (friendly to Jews, that is) and thus didn't rebel (though the rebels in the Great Revolt appear to have thought the Babylonians would open an eastern front against the Romans, but their hopes were dashed), etc etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA You can learn things from where terms come from. To take your example, I have read that Sephardim did not develop an equivalent of the milchig/fleishig terminology because butter and milk were not as prominent in their diet. Also seeing a phrase in only Babylonian Aramaic raises a question if the concept existed earlier of if it was just phrased differently.

Comment: @Mike "learn" is a strong word for such speculation as that about milk, but anyway the point here is the OP searched for a babylonian aramaic term and couldn't find it outside the babylonian talmud and was confused enough to ask here

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%90

Comment: Are you looking for the term by tannaim or the concept, re: @DoubleAA

Comment: @robev I'm with Mike - trying to track down this concept.

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course I'm looking for the concept. I've read the WIKI but it only starts with Mar Samuel. That's why I asked "for the principle".

Comment: According to those who hold there’s no dina in Israel, it would make sense that the term only originated in Babylon

Comment: @AlBerko See the mishna in Nedarim 3:4.

Comment: @ShmuelKoppel I saw, and I didn't find anything related.

Comment: @AlBerko The meforshei hamishna coming off the Gemara there explain the line of ״שהן של בית המלך״ to be because of the fact that dina d’malchusa dina is mechayev him to pay the taxes. I don’t know if you would consider that a tannaic source but that’s what I was referring to.